# Why do I need to allow server ip in web-server config for requests between subdomain on the same server?

Tags: nginx

I'm using nginx as web-server.

I set up basic auth for some my web apps.
Nginx config was like:

```
satisy any;
allow <some_ip>; //but not the ip of current server
deny all;
auth_basic ...;
```

When one of my app was requesting other app resource (via php cURL), there was 401 Unauthorized. Being on `foo.example.com`, app requests resource from `bar.foo.example.com`.

After I've added `allow <my_server_ip>;` it started to work.

Why so? Both apps are on the same server, using same ip and port. Both apps are served through https.

For me it's like when you want to go from kitchen to bathroom, you have to open your front door with the key. Or I don't understand something.

Answer (score 2):

The request from curl is just like any other request. It is either allowed by the configuration, or it is not.

What you suggest is that the effective configuration should not be what is stated in the config file, but something that is modified behind the scene. This usually leads to more problems than it solves.

Regarding your example with the kitchen and the bathroom, most people do have locks on the bathroom door.

Comment: *What you suggest is that the effective configuration should not be what is stated in the config file* I'm afraid if I got you right. You say that I don't have to put such `allow <my_server_ip>;` inside my config?

Comment: I say you should allow my_server_ip in the config file if you want to allow access from my_server_ip.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confused about how the sites are connected. I hope this picture helps to understand the difference between two setups, your current setup being B (or possibly a mix-up of A and B).

[image: comparison]

- **A:** Browser connects to app1 and app2 directly. Authentication `auth_basic;` is used for both.

  - If the apps are on the same host(name) with different path, same authentication works for both.
  - If the apps are on separate host(name)s, authentication is required for both separately.
- **B:** Browser only interacts with app1. Connection to app2 is made using cURL (or PHP) from app1 i.e. **app1 is a client for app2**. The authentication from browser doesn't authenticate app1. Therefore, an additional `allow <ip>;` for app1 is required.